# How to pass sessions in Sinatra

Tags: authentication, session, routes, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I'm trying to implement sessions in my login process, but the session is not being passed from route to route while I'm using set `:session_secret, SecureRandom.hex(64)`, but if I use `set :session_secret, "secret"` it works fine.

From my understanding I am not supposed to do that because it is not very secure.

Is there a way to use `set :session_secret, SecureRandom.hex(64` and have it pass from route to route? Or, do I have to use `set :session_secret, "secret"`?

```
class MainController < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::ActiveRecordExtension
    enable :sessions
    #set :session_secret, SecureRandom.hex(64)
    #set :session_secret, "secret"
    #set :session_secret, "secretsession"
    set :session_secret, "f650ed69344bab0084199bb8cc9aa5a1bd6756c3b57ad67023255af0fc3795057e"
    set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "../views/") }


get '/sessions_set' do 
        session[:foo] = 'hello'
        if session[:foo] == 'hello'
            binding.pry
            redirect '/fetch'
          else
            "Session value has not been set!"
          end
    end 

    get '/fetch' do
        binding.pry
        "You did it! session[:foo] value: #{session[:foo]}.\nMove on to Part II of this lab at '/second_exercise' "
      end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run this every time it will create a different random code every time, making your session unusable essentially. You will have to run this piece of code at startup somehow for it to work.

```
:session_secret, SecureRandom.hex(64)
```

For a quick fix you could run this code in a console and just paste the output into your file as it seems you have already done. For a more secure way you could look into using environment variables.